# This works and displays the string in an EditText but doesn't work with a TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I am having real problems trying to display a string of text using setText on a textview. All my calls to the webservice work, my functions to get the data work and if I use an EditText to display the string, everything is shown correctly but I'd rather the text just appeared on the screen rather than in an EditText as the text is information rather than something to be edited by the user.

This code works for EditText -

```
package xxx.refusecollectionday;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://xxx";
    private static String URL = "http://xxx/Service.asmx";
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xxxx";
    private static String METHOD_NAME1 = "xxx";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String uprn = intent.getStringExtra(AndroidListViewActivity.UPRN).trim();
        String displayText = "";

        //Initialize soap request + add parameters
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);

        //Use this to add parameters
        request.addProperty("UPRN",uprn);

        //Declare the version of the SOAP request
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        try {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

            if(result != null) {                
                String strXML = result.getProperty(0).toString();               
                strXML = sortXMLString(strXML);
                                }
            }else{
                showBalloonPopUp("No Response");
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        displayText = displayText + "\nTo contact the Customer Service Centre:\n";

        EditText txtCollectionResults = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.collectionresults);

        // displaying selected product name
        txtCollectionResults.setText(displayText); 

        //showAlertDialog(displayText);
    }

     public void showBalloonPopUp(String popUpMessage){
        Toast.makeText(this, popUpMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

       public void showAlertDialog(String alertMessage){
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
        ad.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button  
        ad.setMessage(alertMessage);  
        ad.setButton(-1, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
                dialog.dismiss();                      
            }  
        });  
        ad.show(); 
    }

     public String sortXMLString(String stringToCorrect){
        // do stuff

        return stringToCorrect;
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <EditText android:id="@+id/collectionresults"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dip"                 
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:maxLines="50" 
            android:editable="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

but if I change the EditText to a TextView in the xml, the following

```
TextView txtCollectionResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.collectionresults);

        // displaying 
        txtCollectionResults.setText(displayText);
```

doesnt display any text

Comment: Total schoolboy error - White text on a white background ended up being the problem!